# How to fetch millions record in cassandra using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

I want to fetch all the records from the table at a time but if there are millions of records in the table then this may lead performance issue and many other problem. so how can i fetch all the records from the table using the query

```
Select * from tableName;
```

i'm using cassandra version **3.*** , with spring boot framework.

Please give me the solution of this problem.Thank you.

Comment: What performance problems? Are you trying to load a million records into memory on spring app side?

Comment: Fetching all the records of the table is a bad design in itself. You should look at your schema and try to fix that.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink load and time problems and also memory leak problem from cassandra, but i have to fetch all records if know please tell me the solution.

Comment: @AbhishekGarg i know but i need all records from that table to show all users list, if you know the other way of it then please tell me how can i do this

Comment: `memory leak problem from cassandra` ? what leak?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink read timeout error occured